# Curious solutions of x' = Sqrt(x), x(0)=4

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis

Consider the solution of $x'=\sqrt{x}$, $x(0)=4$ using DSolve.

```
DSolve[{x'[t] == Sqrt[x[t]], x[0] == 4}, x[t], t]

(*{{x[t] -> 1/4 (16 - 8 t + t^2)}, {x[t] -> 
   1/4 (16 + 8 t + t^2)}}*)
```

I don't see how $x(t)=\frac14(16-8t+t^2)$, or equivalently, $x(t)=\frac14(4-t)^2$, can be a solution. Consider the following code and graphical output.

```
vp = VectorPlot[{1, Sqrt[x]}, {t, -10, 10}, {x, 0, 10},
   VectorStyle -> {GrayLevel[0.8]},
   VectorScale -> {0.045, 0.9, None}];
plt = Plot[1/4 (4 - t)^2, {t, -10, 10}];
Show[vp, plt, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Clearly, not a solution. This can also be verified by checking algebraically. If $x(t)=\frac14(4-t)^2$, then
$$x'(t)=\frac12(t-4),$$
and
$$\begin{align*}
\sqrt{x}&=\sqrt{\frac14(4-t)^2}\\
&=\frac{|4-t|}{2}\\
&=\frac12(t-4),
\end{align*}$$
only if
$$\begin{align*}
4-t&\le 0\\
-t&\le -4\\
t&\ge 4,
\end{align*}$$
which agrees with the image above. Hence, even though the initial condition $x(0)=4$ is satisfied, the answer only satisfies the original ODE if $t\ge 4$.

So, why does DSolve produce this answer?

Comment: Interesting.  Note also that the second solution doesn't work for $t \leq -4$, by much the same logic.  It appears that Mathematica is integrating through the point $x = 0$ even when it shouldn't.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert. True, but it does satisfy the differential equation for $t\ge -4$ and it satisfies the initial condition $x(0)=4$. So that one works on the interval of existence $(-\infty,-4]$.

Comment: I suspect that `DSolve` is "rationalizing" the differential equation as an early step, turning it into an equation of first order but second degree.  The result of this process would be $(x')^2 = x$, and both of the solutions given above satisfy this equation with the given initial conditions.  Usually Mathematica is hyper-sensitive about square roots and absolute values, though, so it's still a little puzzling.

Comment: You are forgetting that there two square roots for a positive number. You must change the sign of the square root when `x[t]` crosses the branch cut at `t = 4`. Further you are not drawing the vector field correctly. See my answer for details.

Comment: `DSolve[{x'[t] == Surd[x[t], 2], x[0] == 4}, x[t], t]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a sense, the returned solutions are valid, but only over a restricted domain.  We can determine the domain for each solution with something like

```
Reduce[ode && -Infinity < t < Infinity /. sol, t]
```

We can join the domain with the corresponding solution via `ConditionExpression`.

```
ode = {x'[t] == Sqrt[x[t]], x[0] == 4};
dsol = DSolve[ode, x, t];
```

In the form of `x -> function`:

```
intermediate = {x -> Function @@ {t, 
      ConditionalExpression[x[t] /. #, 
       Reduce[And @@ ode && -Infinity < t < Infinity /. #, t]]}} & /@ dsol
(*
  {{x -> Function[t, ConditionalExpression[1/4 (16 - 8 t + t^2), t >= 4]]},
   {x -> Function[t, ConditionalExpression[1/4 (16 + 8 t + t^2), t >= -4]]}}
*)
```

Now, these are solutions, but only one is defined at `t == 0`.  We can select the correct one.

```
newsols = Select[intermediate, (x[0] /. #) =!= Undefined &]
(*
  {{x -> Function[t, ConditionalExpression[1/4 (16 + 8 t + t^2), t >= -4]]}}
*)
```

Both of the `dsol` solutions are solutions to the rationalized ODE `x'[t]^2 == x[t]`, and almost certainly that is from whence the extraneous solution arises.